# Find a point of tangency in a plane from a point to a sphere using spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, solid-geometry

I'm facing a problem very similar to this one, but I can't resolve mine: [find ANY point of tangency from a point to a sphere using spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603287/find-any-point-of-tangency-from-a-point-to-a-sphere-using-spherical-coordinates)

Here's the situation:

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaLUC.jpg)

I know the spherical coordinates of $B$ and $D$. I know the radius of the sphere $S$.
I have the $P$ plane equation in the form $(ax + by + cz + d) = 0$ (that I found by computing vector product of $OB$ and $OD$)

Now I want to get the coordinates of $C$ (which I believe is the unique point of tangency in the plane P). It's similar to the question I've linked because instead of finding **ALL** points, I want to find **THE** point that is in the plane $P$.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: May I rephrase? Given non-$O$ points $B$ and $D$, with $OD$ and $OD$ linearly independent, let $P$ be the plane spanned by $O, B, D$. Now let $S$ be the sphere with center $O$ and radius $r$. The intersection of $S$ and $P$ is a circle $U$; find the point $C \in U$ with $DU$ tangent to $U$.

Comment: If that's the question, it's not solvable, for if the distance from $U$ to $O$ is less than $r$, there's no solution, and if that distance is *larger* than $r$, there are two solutions. Only if the distance is $r$ is there a unique solution, and it's the point $D$.

Comment: Thank you John Hughes for rephrasing my question, I'm not much familiar with english mathematic vocabulary. Let's assume $UO$ distance is larger than $r$, could you please help me figure out what equation has two solutions you arer talking about?

Comment: The two solutions arise by reflecting the plane $P$ through the line $OD$; since the line $OD$ is a diameter of the circle $U$, this sends $U$ to itself, but also sends $C$ to a new point $C' \in U$ where $DC'$ is tangent to $U$.

Comment: Do you need a formula to find the point $C$, or would a sequence of steps (i.e., something like a *program*) to find $C$ be enough?